# how to show all duplicate rows from 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables named DataEntry_old and DataEntry_new with columns doc id, mobileno, name, addr on both tables.

I want to show all matching rows from both the tables where mobileno=987654321.
That is if mobileno=987654321 is in DataEntry_old then one row from this table and if also mobileno=987654321 is in DataEntry_new then another row from this table.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Seems as a job for [union all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can edit your question and add the appropriate tags to it (like SQL-Server, MySQL etc.). This will help us help you!

Comment: Note that matching rows and duplicate rows are different concepts. Duplicate records usually refrers to two or more identical records in the same table. Matching records usually refers to correlated records between two (or more) tables. It seems you are searching for matching records (correlated by the `mobileno` field), even if you want to present them as different records. Have you considered to simply join the tables on the `mobileno` field?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use union all for this query:

```
select t.*
from ((select 'old' as which, doc id, mobileno, name, addr
       from DataEntry_old
      ) union all
      (select 'new' as which, doc id, mobileno, name, addr
       from DataEntry_new
      )
     ) t
where t.mobileno='987654321'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_id, mobileno, name, addr 
FROM DataEntry_old
    ,DataEntry_new
WHERE DataEntry_ol.doc_id = DataEntry_new.doc_id
```

Comment: Don't use the SQL-89 style syntax, especially when teaching new users - It has undefined results when doing some complex joins... `SELECT * FROM DataEntry_old O INNER JOIN DataEntry_new N ON O.mobileno = N.mobileno`

Comment: but it returns just matching data from both tables in a single row twice

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_id, mobileno, name, addr FROM DataEntry_old o inner join  DataEntry_new n
on o.doc_id=n.doc_id
where n.mobileno='987654321'
```